# How to remove double quotation marks when converting from excel to text file?

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I use this code, for some reason, double quotation marks appear for cell's output from beginning to ending. Anyway how I can remove these quotation marks?

I tried using a basic VBA, where it copies data from a certain column and converts it to a txt file.

```
Dim s As String, FileName As String, FileNum As Integer

  ' Define full pathname of TXT file
  FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2019.con"

  ' Copy range to the clipboard
  Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Copy

  ' Copy column content to the 's' variable via clipboard
  With New DataObject
     .GetFromClipboard
     s = .GetText
  End With
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  ' Write s to TXT file
  FileNum = FreeFile
  If Len(Dir(FileName)) > 0 Then Kill FileName
  Open FileName For Binary Access Write As FileNum
  Put FileNum, , s
  Close FileNum
```

`Actual Result:
"CONT=10"
"."
"."
"."`

`Desired Result:
CONT=10
.
.
.`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Print` not `Write` if you don't want the quote marks

Comment: Also consider opening the file `For Output` if you're not writing a binary blob to it

Comment: How would I write it? @Cryostasys

Comment: Change
` Open FileName For Binary Access Write As FileNum
  Put FileNum, , s
  Close FileNum`
To 
`Open FileName For Output As #1
Print #1, s
Close #1`

Comment: `s Close #1` is giving me error. do I need the s? @Cryostasys

Comment: I tried all this, still showing the double quotation marks

Comment: The comment didn't let me line space things properly for display.
The line structure for VBA should go by line numbers:
1 `Open FileName For Output As #1`
2 `Print #1, s`
3 `Close #1`
 The s is the copy of the data that you made in the original code.